# Java: Keep binary file blob in memory for multiple uses (byte[]? ByteBuffer? ...?)

Tags: java, file, byte, in-memory

I read binary files from an `InputStream` and have to keep them in memory for further processing. The most obvious approach is to keep the read data of each file in a `byte[]` array. But I guess there are more elegant ways that provide some OO API around "file blobs" in memory. What would you recommend?

- Multiple reads must be possible without having to rebuild the data structure (read access mustn't affect internal state of the file blob)
- (Random) Write access not required. No need to modify certain bytes
- Finally, after having been inspected by multiple visitors, the file blob kept in memory will be written to disk
- Pure Java 8 only, no third-party libs like Apache Commons, Guava etc.

Comment: Can you keep the entire blob in memory, or do you need to implement some form of stream processing?

Comment: Hi Florian, The files can be kept in memory in their entirety. The files usually aren't larger than a few MB. The memory consumption is not the problem, especially as I need the file contents only temporarily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If everything fits into memory and the data is discarded quickly, use a `byte[]`s or non-direct (!) `java.nio.ByteBuffer`s (which are just wrappers around byte arrays anyway).  Byte buffers have the advantage that you can provide a reference to the same blob through which no changes to the blob can be made, using the `asReadOnlyBuffer()` method.  With `byte[]`, this requires a defensive copy.  Regarding the additional overhead from `ByteBuffer`: The Hotspot compilers are pretty good at eliminating that, and your blobs seem to be fairly large, so the additional allocation should not matter.